# A simple Knight's problem

Tags: code-golf, chess, puzzle-solver

How many ways are there to place a black and a white knight on an N * M chessboard such that they do not attack each other?

A knight can move two squares horizontally and one square vertically, or two squares vertically and one square horizontally.

The knights have to be placed on different squares and the knights attack each other if one can reach the other in one move.

### Input:

The first line contains the number of test cases T. Each of the next T lines contains two integers N and M, representing the dimensions of the board.

### Output:

Output T lines, one for each test case, each containing the required answer for the corresponding test case.

**Sample input**:

```
3
2 2
2 3
4 5
```

**Sample output**:

```
12
26
312
```

**Constraints**

```
    1 <= T <= 10000
    1 <= N,M <= 100000
time limit 1 sec
```

**Source Limit:**

```
50000 Bytes
```

**Winning criteria**

```
Shortest code which runs with specified time limit decides the winner
```

i ll leave two days time for more users to try from today

Comment: I tidied up the formatting a little on your question, I hope you don't mind. Feel free to roll back the edit if you don't like it.

Comment: @Griffin i am new here thanks for the edit ,please correct me if i make mistakes in future

Comment: You're going to want to put a winning criteria on your question before it gets down-voted by all the boring people on this site. You need to have a fairly objective way of choosing a winner. e.g. shortest code, fastest running code for a given input or some point system of your choosing.

Comment: Do we need to worry about board dimensions <= 0?

Comment: @Griffin does my winning criteria ok?

Comment: @vignesh I don't understand your answer. I was asking if a board dimension of 0 is valid inputs, and also if negative board dimensions are valid.

Comment: @Matt, the challenge is based on a very real-world game. You cannot place a knight on a board with negative or zero dimension.

Comment: @matt consider my first input sample and you can clarify it

Comment: @vignesh actually nevermind, you had included that information in the original spec and I just missed it.

Comment: Question appears to be copied from [here](http://www.codechef.com/problems/BWKNIGHT) without any attribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## GNU Octave, 55 <sub><strike>56 58 78 87* 93</strike></sub> chars

```
a=t(:,1);b=t(:,2);-4*max(2*(g=a.*b)-3*(a+b)+4,0)+g.*--g
```

Octave doesn't take input from STDIN, so you've got to provide the input in the program:

```
t = [
    1 7;
    2 2;
    2 3;
    4 5;
    5000 6000 
];                % test cases

a=t(:,1);b=t(:,2);-4*max(2*(g=a.*b)-3*(a+b)+4,0)+g.*--g
```

The logic is as follows:

`nchoosek(n*m, 2)` gives us the number of combinations of two positions we can have on a N*M board. We then multiply it by two since we have two different knights.

Then we work out how many 3*2 blocks fit in an N*M board. For each 3*2 block there are 4 different positions our knights can be attacking each other. So we multiply it by 4 and subtract it from the value we calculated above.

*thanks to a simplification of the nchoosek I shamelessly stole from Matt.

### Edit

I've just tested this on my laptop to make sure it meets the time requirements.

It will compute <strike>500,000</strike> 10,000,000 test cases in an average of <strike>0.918787</strike> 0.231201 seconds

Comment: I can't test yours at the moment, but my solution that was based on yours gives incorrect results for boards of size 1xn, I suspect yours does as well.

Comment: @matt, you are correct, good catch. Also I've just noticed we've come up with the same fix.

Comment: @Griffin I don't know much of the Octave, but can't you use `end` instead of `endfor`?

Comment: @ArtemIce Yes you're right, when I was learning Octave I just assumed I had to end loops like that, silly me. Though I've just realised I don't even need a loop - huge performance increase.

Comment: @griffin excellent answer ,i ll keep my question alive for more solutions if it's your's best then i ll accept it !!!

Answer (score 3):

## Python <strike>105</strike> <strike>119</strike> <strike>112</strike> 104

```
for a,b in[map(int,raw_input().split())for i in[1]*input()]:print a*b*(a*b-1)-4*(max(2*a*b-3*(a+b)+4,0))
```

This uses the same approach as Griffin's solution.

Now appropriately handles boards of size 1xn

Comment: +1 for the `a*b*(a*b-1)`, I forgot the simplify the maths. I might pinch that...

Comment: `(a-2)*(b-1)+(a-1)*(b-2)` can be expanded and simplified to `2*a*b-3*(a+b)+4`

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica <strike>55 50 38</strike> 41

**Second attempt**

This is my rendering, in Mathematica, of  @Matt's solution.
Credit for the underlying reasoning goes to Matt.
Griffin helped me understand how Matt's approach works.

It is faster than my first approach approach but still too slow to satisfy the time constraints for boards with 10^5*10^5 cells.  The pure function (38 chars) is defined as follows:

```
 #1 #2 (#1 #2-1)-4 Max[2 #1 #2-3 (#1+#2)+4,0]&
```

**Usage**

```
#1 #2 (#1 #2-1)-4 Max[2 #1 #2-3 (#1+#2)+4,0]& @@@ {{2, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}

(* out *)
{12, 26, 312}
```

The symbols, `@@@`, apply the function to the list. I included them in the character count.

---

**First Attempt: 50 chars but really, really slow.**

I'm including it because it may be of interest to some readers.

Mathematica doesn't take input from STDIN so I used an input more to its liking. There is no need to input the number of inputs; MMA will simply act on whatever number it is given.

**Code**

```
#1*#2*(#1*#2-1)-2 EdgeCount[#1~KnightTourGraph~#2] &
```

---

**Usage** (with spaces for readability).

```
#1*#2*(#1*#2 - 1) - 2 EdgeCount[#1~KnightTourGraph~#2] &; @@@ {{2,2}, {2,3}, {4,5}}

(* out *)
{12, 26, 312}
```

---

**Explanation**

Below is a graph of possible knight moves in a 4 by 5 chessboard.

```
k = KnightTourGraph[i, j, PlotLabel -> Subscript[K, i, j]]
```

[image: graph]

There are `20*19 = 380` ways to arrange the black and white knight on the board.
Below is the adjacency matrix:

```
AdjacencyMatrix[k] // MatrixForm
```

[image: adjacency]

There are `68` cases in which the knights are in an attacking position. This corresponds tohow many one's there are in the matrix.  It also happens to equal two times the number of edges and sum of the degrees of the vertices.

```
t = 2*EdgeCount[k]
(* out *)
68
```

Finally, `380-68 = 312`.

---

**Timing**

It takes just under one second to calculate the answer for all grids up to 15 by 15.
Note: `312` is in row 4, column 5.

[image]

Comment: Do your timings include time to ouput (which I don't think they should)? Because you need to be able to calculate answers for grids up to 100000x100000.

Comment: Time to output is not included. (The `;` suppresses that.) The routine seems to be relatively slow.

Comment: Why don't you take the conditionals out? Octave (pretty much MATLAB with some syntactic sugar I prefer) is interpreted too. Maybe using a table is slowing you down?

Comment: That was my first thought but the timing without the conditionals was just the same. I'll try using an alternative to Table. Thanks.

Comment: @Griffin.  The timing is slightly faster (2x) with Do loops and no conditionals. There must be a better way.

Comment: I don't know enough about what Mathematica is optimised for to offer any suggestions. Maybe try compiling your function? http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Compile.html

Comment: I've been playing with compiling but I'll need some time to become proficient in compiling.  My attempts presently bail out with large tables.

Comment: It's annoying me greatly that I can't beat your 50 chars!

Comment: If it's any consolation, my first approach does not satisfy the time constraints of the problem. So, technically, my only valid approach takes 76 chars.

Answer (score 1):

## C++, <strike>232</strike> <strike>250</strike> <strike>228</strike> <strike>192</strike> 173 characters

```
#include<iostream>
int main(){long long n,x,y,i;for(std::cin>>n;n--;)std::cin>>x>>y,i=(x*2-2)*(y-2<0?0:y-2)+(y*2-2)*(x-2<0?0:x-2)<<1,x*=y,std::cout<<x*x-x-i<<"\n";return 0;}
```

[SEE IT RUN](http://ideone.com/pXXdb)

I don't know what hardware ideone uses, but that can run for a 10000x10000 board 10000 times in .2 seconds.

How I simplified the problem:

I started out trying to find ways I could divide the board into known regions, with a certain density of bad positions per square.  The simplest case is that if there are no edges within 2 squares of a square, that square has 8 possible failing positions.  This turned out to be really complicated near the edges of the board where more than 2 edges can sometimes come into play (if, for example, you have a board that's only 2 wide), so I decided to try to simplify it based on direction, which turned out to be very easy.

First, I considered just one direction.  On a chessboard of irrelevant length, how many moves are eliminated by the introduction of one unit of width?  I made a table:

```
Width of board         Number of positions eliminated
1                      0
2                      2
3                      4
4                      6
N                      2N-2
```

I used my E=2N-2 formula along with the knowledge that for a board of length L, L-2 rows are viable (and thus count towards the exclusion count).

The program, conceptually, makes 4 sweeps, one in each direction (in practice it does 2, and multiplies by 2.  It's a shortcut that works because of symmetry).  Each sweep represents the moves excluded that tend in the direction of the sweep.  The program then sums up each of the sweeps and subtracts from the total number of possible combinations.

Knight placement is random, but two knights cannot occupy the same space.  Therefore, the total number of positions you can place a knight is the total numbers of squares the first time, then the number of squares minus one the second time (since there is a square that's taken).

## EDIT 1

fixed overflow, fixed forgetting to substract somewhere causing incorrect answers with a dimension of 1.  Also swapped out 31's for 63's in bit twiddling since it uses 64 bit data types now

## EDIT 2

shortened further (introduced branching D: the non-branching version is 6 characters longer.)

## GOLF SCORECARD

- removed unnecessary clause: `(~u>>31&(x<<1)-2)` became `((x*2)-2)` in 2 places, saved 16 characters (234)
- swapped `~u>>63&u` for `u<0?0:u` in 2 places, saving 2 characters (232)
- swapped `x-2<0?0:x-2` for `u<0?0:u` and removed definition of u `u=x-2,` in 2 places, saving 4 characters (228, shorter than original solution)
- removed function f and moved functionality into main, saved 28 characters (200)
- removed `using namespace std;` and used std::cout, std::cin, and "\n", saved 5 characters (195)
- changed `std::cin>>n;for(;n>0;--n)` to `for(std::cin>>n;n;--n)`, saved 3 characters (192)
- removed `typedef long long L;` since its only used in one place now, saved 12 characters (180)
- removed 4 parens from statements like `((x*2)-2)`, saved 4 characters (176)
- removed brackets from loop by using commas instead of semicolons, compressed loop condition from `std::cin>>n;n;--n` to `std::cin>>n;n--;`, saved 3 characters (173)

Comment: This gives the wrong result for boards of size `1xn`

Comment: @Matt: yeah I forgot to subtract when checking for positivity.  fixed now

Comment: Alright, I think we're maximally golfed.

Comment: I don't know too much C++ but can't `y-2<0?0:y-2` be changed to `max(y-2,0)`?

Comment: @Griffin: I'd need to #include<algorithm> and use std::max.  Good suggestion though.  I always forget about little things like that that the STL provides for me and roll my own wheel.

Comment: Aha, well there is another saving. Changing `<<1` to `*2`

Comment: @Griffin: thought of that too.  I'd need to wrap the rest of the expression in parens, so I'd gain a character.  (as it is it works because + takes precedence over <<)

Comment: Haha ok, last suggestion: http://ideone.com/zOBrg changed the loop conditional and removed the braces around the loop body by replacing all the semicolons with commas.

Comment: That one I'll add.  I've done that in all of my other golfs with c and c++, don't know why I forgot :D.  We're definitely squeezing water from the proverbial rock now. we've hit the C++ degeneracy pressure. If we compress it any further, it will decay into python. :D

Comment: You can remove `int ` before `main` and you can remove the `return 0;` and if you compile as 64bit, you can remove one of the longs.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-c Also, if I omit the return statement, ideone throws a signal.  The code provided is the shortest possible cross platform, standards compliant code (at least I think it is.  Disregarding the fact that I don't think long long HAS to be 64 bits, it just tends to be).

Answer (score 1):

## Go

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    var N int
    fmt.Scanln(&N)
    for ; N > 0; N-- {
        var m, n int64
        fmt.Scanln(&m, &n)
        grid := m*n
        total := grid*(grid-1)
        if m > 2 && n > 1 {
            total -= (m - 2)*(n - 1) * 4
        }
        if n > 2 && m > 1 {
            total -= (n - 2)*(m - 1) * 4
        }
        fmt.Println(total)
    }
}
```

### Explanation

- `grid` is number of grid
- `total` is initialized as all the possible ways the knights could be placed. Since they have to be different grids, `grid * (grid - 1)`
- Now we exclude the number of ways they may attack each other

  - Their position could be two squares difference horizontally and one square vertically. The number of ways is `(m - 2)*(n - 1)` when `m > 2 && n > 1`. The left can be higher of lower then the right, so `*2`. White and black are exchangable, so `*2` again.
  - Similar to the situation for two squares vertically and one square hotizontally

### Timing

- 4 `int64` multiplication and 7 `int64` plus/minus operation, should be done in 1 second.